# Laravel - Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery error

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, laravel, twitter-bootstrap-3

While adding navbar from bootstrap css in my laravel project, am having an issue with the Dropdown Menu...the Menu is not getting cascaded. While checking html element from the browser have found the following error...

> Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery error

And following is the CDNs, I have used in my master file...

```
<head>
<meta charset="uth-8">
<title>@yield('title')</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">

</head>
<body>
@include('layouts.partials.header')
@yield('content')
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 </body>
```

Can anyone please help me with this issue...though have googled it and found this issue should be taken care in bootstrap3.3.7 edition am with no luck...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to load jQuery before you load Bootstrap JS ... not Bootstrap JS twice!

```
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>@yield('title')</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">

</head>
<body>
@include('layouts.partials.header')
@yield('content')
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 </body>
```

And it's `utf-8`not `uth-8`